# create a grid with the first 3 children with different dimensions

Tags: css, css-grid

I want to make a grid where item 1 has twice the width and 2 and 3 have half the height of the rest of the elements.

[image]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
}

.articles {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 45% repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.articles-item {
  grid-row: span 2;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #FF4F4F;
  color: #fff;
}

.articles-item:nth-child(2),
.articles-item:nth-child(3) {
  grid-row: span 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="articles">
  <div class="articles-item">1</div>
  <div class="articles-item">2</div>
  <div class="articles-item">3</div>
  <div class="articles-item">4</div>
  <div class="articles-item">5</div>
  <div class="articles-item">6</div>
  <div class="articles-item">7</div>
  <div class="articles-item">8</div>
  <div class="articles-item">9</div>
  <div class="articles-item">10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should paste your code right here (as formatted text within your question),instead of linking somewhere.

Comment: Your codepen URL 404s. Please include the code directly in your question.

Comment: thanks, the code that is above helped me with the problem, sorry, delete the codepen because I already had several, to the next I will attach the code, I still do not know how, I am new